# How can I get a list of genes from a list of refseq accession numbers (NM_<num> and NR_<num>)

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I am using python 2.7 and trying to use biopython or pyensembl to obtain a list of genes from a list of refseq accession numbers. Is there a simple way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a simple way. But you should always show some effort, some code you tried before asking. This is the code you need:

```
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = "trouselife@gmail.com"

handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id="NM_123456", retmode="xml")
record = Entrez.read(handle)

for feature in r[0]["GBSeq_feature-table"]:
    for qualifier in feature["GBFeature_quals"]:
        if "gene" in qualifier["GBQualifier_name"]:
            print(qualifier["GBQualifier_value"])

# MHK7.14; MHK7_14
```

You should get some samples in the `efetch` line, and then find the data you want to extract from the handler you get.